# Magento 1.7 reindex catalogsearch_fulltext

Tags: magento, search, catalog, reindex

We have a multi-store/store-view installation, with 4 stores and 22 storeviews at all.
We also have 446k products.

The problem: indexing catalogsearch_fulltext isn't possible, because it is generating 1 entry for every product at every store_id. 
446k * 22 = way too much.

I'm looking for a solution to improve the reindexing process, so that only one entry is generated for every product. Is there any useful extension or workaround to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about free solutions, but this extenion preatty cool http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blast-lucene-search-advanced-search-indexing.html

it's saving index in files, not database, and also allow you to do reindex for 1 store only (and after that you can create symbolic links for all other stores - to use same index)

Comment: No problem if its no free solution. The Problem with saving to file to file is, we also use sphinxsearch which needs catalogsearch_fulltext to reindex.